# Is it all files which located in documents folder on iOS app will be backed-up?

Tags: ios, swift, file, icloud

I created iOS app , and saved some files like (images , text) in **Documents folder** of App , but I don't add these keys (**`UIFileSharingEnabled , LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace`**) into **`Info.plist`** , so these files will not shown in **`App File`** of iOS .

My question ,is these files will be backed-up to iCloud automatically?

If the answer yes , can I browse these files in iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to view files from iCloud backup